How to connect with a device using pairing code entered from textfield in flutter?
User input is taken from the App(TextField), when bonding with the device i need to pass this pairing code to the device from the App, currently a system dialog appear on initiating bonding with the device.
is there any way to pass pairing code from App using flutterblueplus,or from platform channel without entering pairing code manually in system dialog.

You want to remove the system dialog?
